# how to set input charset to unicode in VB.net or VC++.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, unicode, utf-8, browser

Hi there fellow programmers..

i am using Web Browser control in VB.net 2005, the application i wrote shows a webpage on my computer which has 2 text areas, one for input, and the other for output.

my problem is, i need the charset of the whole program to be unicode, coz the charset of the webpage is utf8. and right now, when i process the input text, the output looks like this:

> undefinedundifinedundefinedundifinedundefinedundifinedundefinedundifined

any ideas about how i can change the input language of the entire program to utf-8 or unicode ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

never mind, turned out the program already accepts unicode input, its the javascript inside the webpage that i am using that's creating the error..